# reshape problem in R: it does not consider all variables

Tags: r, reshape

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) question about reshape and I tryed to use on my dataset.

But when I use it, my new dataset doen't have all the column requested and repeat some variables.

My actual dataset is like this:

```
a1 <- c("10/10/2023  00:00:08","10/10/2023  00:00:08","10/10/2023  00:00:08", "10/10/2023  00:00:08", "10/10/2023  00:00:16", "10/10/2023  00:00:16", "10/10/2023  00:00:16", "10/10/2023  00:00:16")
b1 <- c(7, 7, 7,5, 4, 4, 3, 3)
c1 <- c("A","B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D")
m1 <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1)
```

and I want something like this:

```
time <- c("10/10/2023  00:00:08","10/10/2023  00:00:16")
A <- c(7, 4)
B <- c(7, 4)
C <- c(7, 3)
D <- c(5, 3)
m <- data.frame(time, A, B, C, D)
```

my actual code is this, and for this example it works:

```
reshape(m1, idvar = "a1", timevar = "c1", direction = "wide")
```

In my original dataset i have more variables than the example dataset. It is a problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example that *doesn’t* work, including your desired output? This will be much more useful than working code. Good luck!

Comment: I use the same code I proposed, but with my dataset doesn't work because it repeat some variables and doesn't considere some others. I can't include my original dataset, but my code and issue are those

Comment: What I’m saying is that you should include a sample dataset where the code doesn’t work. For example, provide more variables in the sample dataset. Then also include the (wrong) output, and desired output from those example data

Comment: Difficult to give meaningful advice when the given code works, but you can try using `tidyr`s `pivot_wider`, e.g. `library(tidyr); pivot_wider(m1, names_from=c1, values_from=b1)` and see if it works better on the original data.

Comment: if you're unable to provide actual data where it doesn't work (e.g. because of privacy reasons), then instead create a small dataframe with fake data where it is possible to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though what you show above is working, the full function should be as:

```
reshape(m1, idvar = "a1", timevar = "c1", v.names=c("b1"), direction = "wide")
```

You should always make sure you include `v.names` parameter for all the variables that will become multiple columns in wide format. This maybe the reason why "your full data set doesn't have all the columns after reshaping"

Comment: Welcome to SO Joy. While your answer offers good general advice and *may* solve the OP's issue, SO is focused on reproducible questions and answers. As the OP has not provided their full dataset, or a sample dataset that reproduces their issue, there's no way to validate whether your answer is correct. The OP has commented that "it repeat some variables and doesn't consider some others". As such, there may be issues not solved by explicitly declaring `v.names`. Even if your answer does solve the OP's issue, it is still better to include an example dataset that produces the error and then you c

Comment: Sorry, message got cut off: ...and then you can prove your solution works. That is why others have commented as such on the question. Thanks